# Adding repository error

Tags: command-line, package-management, add-apt-repository

I'm trying to add a repository on my VPS with Ubuntu 12.04 installed using this command :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

But terminal is showing

> command not found

Then I've entered the following command to solve the problem

```
sudo apt-get install software-proprieties-common
```

But unfortunately I'm getting the following error :

```
E: Unable to locate package software-proprieties-common
```

How can I solve this problems?

**Update**

Now software-properties-common installed, but same problem continues. Please check the screen shot.[image]

**Update 2**

Problem continues 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

then

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

Comment: Please check that, I've already entered "sudo apt-get install software-properties-common", but it's showing "Unable to loate package software-properties-common". :(

Comment: pleasecheck your command,it is not `software-proprieties-common` it is `software-properties-common`

Comment: try without `sudo`.

Comment: Unfortunately, problem continues. Please check update.

Comment: it is `python-software-properties` not `python-properties-common`.

Comment: I have the same issue, and neither package is available. In fact, `apt-cache search properties` comes up entirely empty. Have I somehow hosed my system in some way? I am also missing some other packages, which makes me feel like apt is just very confused.